# Wait for an approval still waiting -power automate

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I have created the following flow mentioned in the images
It gets stuck on wait for approval even after I approved them

[The flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHkuE.png)

[image: While it runs]

This issue comes randomly and not all the time. Most of the time it runs well. Please help me out in solving this

Comment: You will need to ask Microsoft. This site is for coding related questions.

Comment: I did ask no responses yet @Aldert